# Derivative of expectation: $\sum_{i=1}^N E \left[ \frac{1}{2} \log (1+ap_i) \right]$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, partial-derivative, expectation

I am trying to find the derivative of the following function:

$$C(\mathbf{p})= \sum_{i=1}^N E \left[ \frac{1}{2} \log (1+ap_i) \right],$$

with respect to $p_i$. Where $p_i$ are elements of the vector $\mathbf{p}$ and $a$ is constant. $C(\mathbf{p})$ is the capacity of fading channel when the channel state information is not available at the transmitter (this is why there is expectation). I am trying to solve the maximization problem: 
$$\text{max } C(\mathbf{p})$$
$$\text{subject to } \sum_{i=1}^N p_i \leq NP$$
We have $N$ channels and $P$ is the maximum power that can be achieved on eaxh channel. 
In order to solve the maximization problem I have to solve the Lagrangian of it but I am not sure how to take the partial derivative of $p_i$ when it is in the expectation. The answer of the problem in this situation should be $p_i^*=P$.

Comment: If $a$ is constant, why do even need the expectation?

Comment: It is given like that in the literature. It is capacity formula and I would like to solve a maximization problem with respect to $C(p)$, so I need take the Lagrangian but I am not sure how to take the derivative in the expextation.

Comment: Well, depending on context, taking the derivative inside of an expectation is allowed. However, context here is lacking. Perhaps you should add a little more detail to the problem - until it becomes clear why there is an expectation involved, it is going to be difficult to help you.

Comment: Thank you, I added more details.